# mySql on nodejs JOIN

Tags: mysql

I would like only select message and username from the mysql JOIN result. how do I do that? Appreciated.

[image: Inner join]

[image: table structure]

Comment: add specific columns rather * ,you can get desired output

Comment: I tried, select messages.message users.username from messages LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id; and it returned an error. guess becuase I put users.username when I do FROM only from messages? I could not putw both messages users after FROM. suggestion?

Comment: post your table structure of users and messages

Comment: @utility, just updated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inner Join can give you the desired output :

```
SELECT        messages.message, users.username
FROM            messages INNER JOIN
                         users ON messages.user_id = users.id
```